# Как правильно сделать анимацию?

Tags: java, android, анимация

Делаю простейшую анимацию нужно, чтоб картинка как бы подпрыгнула и вернулась на место. Для этого у есть такой XML

```
<scale
    android:duration="50"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:repeatCount="3"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" />
```

Эффект подпрыгивания я хочу сделать просто за счет увеличения картинки в 2 раза за очень короткий период времени (50 мс), но проблема в том, что картинка в моем случае увеличивается из левого верхнего угла, насколько я знаю из левого верхнего угла в принципе все начинает отрисовываться на экране девайса и за счет этого моя каринка увеличивается не из середины в стороны, а с левого угла и получается совсем не то, на что рассчитывалось...

**Помогите исправить, как сделать так, чтоб картинка увеличивалась из середины?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
 <scale
        android:duration="50"
        android:fromXScale=".2"
        android:fromYScale=".2"
        android:pivotX="60%"
        android:pivotY="60%"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вот только по ссылке там немного другой пример обьясняется...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko рад был помочь:) по ссылке действительно другое решение, просто это первое что пришло в голову))